# Comma separated list with AvroStorage in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I tried to load several files with AvroStorage in Pig by using a comma separated list. The statement I used is:

```
test_data= LOAD 'repo_1/part-r-00000.avro,repo_2/part-r-00000.avro' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

Pig states that no input paths were specified in job. Please see the stacktrace below.
I tried pig version0.8.1-cdh3u2 and 0.9.1.

Does anyone observe the same behavior? Is it a bug or a feature?

Stacktrace:

```
rg.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: No input paths specified in job
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:270)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Those part files are loaded automatically by Pig, so you only need to specify the directory.

Try

```
test_file1 = LOAD 'repo_1' using AvroStorage();
test_file2 = LOAD 'repo_2' using AvroStorage();
test_file = UNION test_file1, test_file2;
```